# On Click of Anchor, How to target a LI that does not have any ULs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a simple menu that has an arrow within the anchor. I have jQuery that adds a class to show the arrow on click. However I need it to NOT "show the arrow" on click if the clicked li a doesn't have a submenu. Here's a rough example of my menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">TopLevel_LinkOne <img src="img/down-carat.png" class="down-carat"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TopLevel_LinkTwo <img src="img/down-carat.png" class="down-carat"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TopLevel_LinkThree <img src="img/down-carat.png" class="down-carat"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Link One <img src="img/down-carat.png" class="down-carat"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Link Two <img src="img/down-carat.png" class="down-carat"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Link Three <img src="img/down-carat.png" class="down-carat"></a></li>        
        </ul>   
    </li>        
</ul>
```

In this example I do not want the arrow to show, if "TopLevel_LinkOne" or "TopLevel_LinkTwo" is clicked. I can't remove the arrow image because it's being added automatically by the nav walker in Wordpress.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('#menu li a').click(  
function() {
    $('ul li a').removeClass('show-arrow'); // Remove any previous arrows
        if('some jquery here that checks if THIS has submenu') {
          $(this).addClass('show-arrow'); // Show the arrow image
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if($(this).parent().find('ul').length) {
      $(this).addClass('show-arrow'); // Show the arrow image
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
if($(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').length > 0)
```

Full code:

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li a').removeClass('show-arrow'); // Remove any previous arrows
    if($(this).closest('li').find('ul.sub-menu').length) {
      $(this).addClass('show-arrow'); // Show the arrow image
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML allows you to make certain assumptions, you can do this really easily.

For example, if it's a safe assumption that your list items will only ever contain either "just a single `<a>` element", *or* "a single `<a>` element followed by a submenu", then you can just do:

```
if( this.parentNode.children.length > 1)
```

But if you want robustness, you could do this:

```
if( $("ul",this.parentNode).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li a').removeClass('show-arrow'); // Remove any previous arrows
       if($(this).siblings('ul').length) {
          $(this).addClass('show-arrow'); // Show the arrow image
       }
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/MHg67/3/

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This one might just work for you:

```
$('#menu > li').click(function () {
    $('ul li a').removeClass('show-arrow');
    $(this).has('ul.sub-menu').addClass('show-arrow');
}
```

You can modify it accordingly to suit your needs. Thanks!